# Ext JS tree, childNodes empty before I expand root node (Load full tree structure)

Tags: extjs, tree

I load **FULL** tree structure at first time.

```
var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    title   : 'Simple Tree',
    width   : 300,
    height  : 300,
    root    : new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
        children : [
            { text :  'one',    leaf : true },
            { text :  'two',    leaf : true },
            { text :  'three',  leaf : true }
        ]
    })
});
Ext.onReady(function(){
    tree.render(Ext.getBody());
});
```

and try this..

```
treePanel.root.childNodes // []
```

But after I expand root node and try again

```
treePanel.root.childNodes // [obj, obj, obj]
```

Can I get childNodes without expand root node ?

Comment: @amol, I update a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `childNodes` is only populated with actual elements. Before you expand that node they are not needed.

What you are looking for is `treePanel.root.attributes.children`. That has three elements in it.

Comment: If I do need the childNodes(for the checkbox reason, when I check father node, all childNodes also checked, but not need expand), then How can I do?